# Need bevel gear for SG90 servo motor

Tags: gears, servo

I am looking for a away I can convert the horizontal rotation into vertical, typically we use bevel gear for such thing. 
But I am using a SG90 servo motor for which I am struggling to get the correct gears to achieve my requirement.

I am not sure is there is any other way I can do this using the SG90 servo motor. I am looking for something which I can 3D print if nothing is readily available.

Comment: a flexible cable as used for drills...

Comment: Do you any image or youtube video to show how it works?

Comment: Do a google search - Bowden cable may be a good start...

Comment: Link to a data sheet.  I suspect that you mean the Tower Pro SG90 RC servo (which is **not** a "servo motor", regardless of what people may call it) -- but no one can be sure.

Comment: Why can't you mount the servo on it's side?  Do you need both vertical and horizontal motion?

Comment: I need to mount it on side so I don't have increase the height of whole assembly as the height of motor is around 20mm or 2 cm, if I put it on sides it would be around 10mm. So I am looking for a Bevel gear which I can fit into motor so can rotate a gear along x axis and have motor rotate on Y axis.